# Tapestry properties in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tapestry

I have two files: "Index.properties", "Index_es.properties" for multilenguage in Tapestry.
I want to read literals from those files in a *.js file, for example:

```
 **Index.properties:**
    menu=Main menu
    menu-welcome=Welcome to my webpage


  **Index_es.properties:**
    menu=Menú principal
    menu-welcome=Bienvenido a mi página web


  **Index.tml:**
      ...
      <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"
    src="${context:/javaScript/menu.js}"></script>
      ...

  **menu.js:**
       ...
       var currentOption=$('#activemenu').attr('name');
       if (currentOption=="menu"){
         $("#button1txt").text("${message:option1}");
       }
       ...
```

How can I read the files since "menu.js"?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## About expansions

Expansions only work in your templates (.tml files) or in the component classes if you are using the `@Component` annotation, for example.

Component parameter documentation:

https://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html

You cannot access files in JavaScript that are stored on the server. But you could pass them along with your script’s init script.

### How to add custom scripts to your pages

Don’t do this to your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="${context:/javaScript/menu.js}"></script>
```

Do this instead to your page class:

```
@Import(library = { "context:javaScript/menu.js" })
public class Index {

}
```

Read the documentation about this feature to learn more: http://tapestry.apache.org/javascript.html

## Solution to your problem

With all that knowledge you’ll now rather want to pass the translations for your menu script like this:

```
@Import(library = { "context:javaScript/menu.js" })
public class Index {
    
    @Inject
    private Messages messages;

    @Inject
    private JavaScriptSupport javaScriptSupport;

    void afterRender() {

        javaScriptSupport.addInitializerCall("initMenu", new JSONObject()
            put("option1", messages.get("option1"))
        );
    }
}
```

*menu.js*

```
(function( $, window ) {

  'use scrict';

  $.extend(Tapestry.Initializer, {
    initMenu: function (spec) {
      var currentOption=$('#activemenu').attr('name');
      if (currentOption=="menu"){
        $("#button1txt").text(spec.option1);
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery, window);
```